# Jquery sorting div (descending order) based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ajax function which actually pull this message_count data from server every 3 mins and update the attribute of each player accordingly... now i want to get the divs automatically gets sorted after this ajax call based on message_count attribute value in descending order... so the player who got more messages will come as first div.

```js
var sortedDivs = jQuery(".players").find(".player").toArray().reverse(sorter);
jQuery.each(sortedDivs, function(index, value) {
  jQuery(".players").append(value);
});

function sorter(a, b) {
  return a.getAttribute('message_count') - b.getAttribute('message_count');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="players">
  <div class="player" message_count="8">8</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="2">2</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="0">0</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="1">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `sort` instead of `reverse` i.e. `jQuery(".players").find(".player").sort(sorter).appendTo(".players");
function sorter(a, b) {
  return b.getAttribute('message_count') - a.getAttribute('message_count');
};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jquery `.sort` will do it easily

```js
var players = $(".players div");
var temp = players.sort(function(a,b){
  return parseInt($(b).attr("message_count")) - parseInt($(a).attr("message_count"));
});
$(".players").html(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="players">
  <div class="player" message_count="8">Div 8</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="2">Div 2</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="0">Div 0</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="1">Div 1</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: would this work for sorting by values that are iso date strings? eg `new Date().toISOString() //   2018-09-22T05:51:53.731Z`

Comment: can you add your question and share the link here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('div').sort(function (a, b) {

      var contentA =parseInt( $(a).attr('message_count'));
      var contentB =parseInt( $(b).attr('message_count'));
      return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
   })
```

Comment: numeric sort is simpler just doing valueA-valueB the same way OP is doing

Comment: Code only answers might solve the issue, but some explanation of how it solves the problem would help in learning to understand how to solve future problems.

Comment: What if we wanted to sort strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and just reverse the query.

```
.sort(function(a, b){return b.getAttribute('message_count') - a.getAttribute('message_count'))
```

```js
var sortedDivs = jQuery(".players").find(".player").toArray().sort(function(a, b){return parseInt(b.getAttribute('message_count')) - parseInt(a.getAttribute('message_count'))});

jQuery.each(sortedDivs, function(index, value) {
  jQuery(".players").append(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="players">
  <div class="player" message_count="8">8</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="2">2</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="0">0</div>
  <div class="player" message_count="1">1</div>
</div>
```